# sqlplus doesn't work in Crontab

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, sql

```
/oracle/GR1/121/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF >> $LOGFILE
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo on;
set serveroutput on;
STARTUP;
EXIT
EOF
```

Already tried it with the path, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: What is in the $LOGFILE? DO you get any mail from this cron run?

Comment: $LOGFILE is just the path to my logfile. This is just a part of my script.

Comment: What is inside this log?

Comment: Things like:
``----------------------------------
START ORACLE DB AND SERVICES
---------------------------------------
Oracle Database is starting on GR1 on 20.02.20 at 13:24

---------------------------------------
CHECK DATABASE STATE
---------------------------------------
Check if database is online with Brconnect and R3trans...
ERROR: Database is offline. Database has to be online. (Brconnect)``

Comment: is this code working in the foreground? and what error we are getting while running as a script...

Comment: can u confirm whether the cron job is scheduled for oracle user?

Comment: So, if i execute `/oracle/GR1/121/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba` i get into the sqlplus menu, but if i do the same in cron i don't get. It is executed with the oracle user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run successfully in cron such job you need to set some variables like `ORACLE_SID`, `ORACLE_HOME` and so on. The samples way to do this is to make your script on this way:

```
source ~/.bashrc #or .bash_profile
/oracle/GR1/121/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF >> $LOGFILE
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo on;
set serveroutput on;
STARTUP;
EXIT
EOF
```

The source command will get the variables from your login and add them to the environment where you exec this task.

Comment: Thank you so much, Romeo! It work's fine!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set related env variables in the cron file before running the cron.

Run `env` or `export`, search for oracle relevant variables and copy them into the cronfile.

Additionally read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-EC18C4A6-3BA5-4C14-9D76-B0DD62FEFFF2.htm#ADMQS12369) ;)

Comment: Can you give me an example?